# Replace in regex pattern with group from another pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like

```
a#?.text1
```

I have two other strings like `c#1.text2` and `d#2.text3`

I want to replace #? in `a#?.text1` with `a#1.text1` if I choose `c#1.text2`. If I choose `d#2.text3`, then I want to replace `a#?.text1` with `a#2.text1`. What is the easiest way to do this? I came up with a solution using groups, but my team doesn't think it is an efficient way of doing it. Here's my Java code:

```
Pattern strPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(#\\?)(\\.\\w+)");
Pattern replacePattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(#\\d+)(\\.\\w+)");

Matcher strMatcher = strPattern.matcher("a#?.text1");
Matcher replaceMatcher1 = replacePattern.matcher("c#1.text2");
Matcher replaceMatcher2 = replacePattern.matcher("d#2.text3");

if(strMatcher.matches() && replaceMatcher1.matches()) {
  String number = replaceMatcher1.group(2);
  return strMatcher.replaceAll(strMatcher.group(1) + number + strMatcher.group(3));
} else if(strMatcher.matches() && replaceMatcher2.matches()) {
  String number = replaceMatcher2.group(2);
  return strMatcher.replaceAll(strMatcher.group(1) + number + strMatcher.group(3));
}
```

The feedback I got was that groups are inefficient and I have to find an easier way to do this.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So looks like you just want to extract the number after `#` from your two strings which are `c#1.text2` and `d#2.text3` and replace `?` just after `#` in `a#?.text1` string.

The code you've written seems a little much where you're created two `Pattern` and then you're doing replacement using `Matcher` objects by capturing three groups, where as this can be easily done with some shorter codes without needing to create two `Pattern` object.

Just extract the number you need to replace and then replace it in the string directly using `replaceFirst` method on `String` object itself using these codes,

```
Pattern replacePattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+#(\\d+)\\.\\w+");
Matcher m = replacePattern.matcher("c#1.text2"); // same way for d#2.text3
if (m.matches()) {
    String digit = m.group(1); // the digit you wanted to extract
    String retVal = "a#?.text1".replaceFirst("(?<=#)\\?", digit); // replace ? preceded by # with the digit using replaceFirst
    System.out.println(retVal); // prints a#1.text1
    return retVal;
} else {
    System.out.println("String doesn't match the pattern");
}
```

Overall your codes can compactly be written as,

```
Pattern replacePattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+#(\\d+)\\.\\w+");
Matcher m = replacePattern.matcher("c#1.text2"); // same way for d#2.text3
if (m.matches()) {
    return "a#?.text1".replaceFirst("(?<=#)\\?", m.group(1)); // returns a#1.text1
}
```